# Are there aspects of non-associative algebras which cannot be captured using Category Theory?

Tags: category-theory, nonassociative-algebras

Category theory uses morphisms, which are associative by definition.  This means that non-associative operations cannot be trivially mapped into morphisms.  One must find clever ways to deal with this.  For instance, [loops and quasigroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup) have an operation that cannot be treated as a morphism because it is non-associative.  Instead, one must construct a system which is isomorphic to these loops with twice as many operators: "multiply on the left" operators and "multiply on the right" operators (The $L_x$ and $R_x$ operators on the Wikipedia page linked above)

So, in this case, we can study loops because we can construct an associative operation which is isomorphic to the loop operator.  But can this be done in general?  Can we always fully study a non-associative system in this way?  Or are there systems which defy such manipulation, such that some statements about the system cannot be made using category theory but can be made using a proof system tailored to the non-associative system?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking if every nonassociative algebraic gadget can be realized as a category with some bonus structure. For instance, groups are categories with one object and every morphism is an iso, and it sounds like you want a similar representation theorem for nonassociative "grouplike" algebras. Is that right?

Comment: @hallasurvivor that sounds about right.  That and, when said "bonus structure" is added, is that sufficient to "completely" analyze the structure.  I'm a little nervous about nailing down my wording too much, in case there is either a different way of dealing with such "gadget", or if those studying the "gadget" directly may find value in phrasings that category theorists may not be interested (having a hammer and seeing the world as a nail)

Comment: Morphisms of algebras are still functions, so still associative, whether the algebras are or not. Homomorphisms are not abelian even if our category is commutative rings or groups, say.

Comment: [This MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82526/) may be what you are looking for?

Comment: @user10354138 If I'm understanding their question, they are looking for a generalized category like entity, but not necessarily making sense of said entity using category theory.